# Is there a way to prevent DOM removal in Angular 2 RC5?

Tags: javascript, dom, angular, touch, ngfor

I'm having issues with Angular 2 and **touch devices**. In particular, when a Component is rendered via NgFor and is (touch) dragged about the screen. The issue arises if a re-render of the NgFor occurs during a touch drag (due to an external event updating the data bound to the NgFor, which is common in my app). **The `touchmove` events stop firing**, and require you to lift your finger and place it back down again, which is a terrible mobile experience. This issue does not occur if you use a mouse.

Essentially, in my app I listen for the `touchstart` event on my component, show another 'DragComponent' via a conditional `*ngIf="isDragging"` (which is not within the NgFor) and it is moved about the screen based on the `touchmove` event position data.

I know why this happens. It's due to the browser implementation of the Touch Spec. I normally code around this issue in vanilla js via keeping the DOM element in memory until the `touchend` or `touchcancel` event fire. However, Angular now controls the DOM! And they are removing the element while it's still in use!

Check out this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/QR6WDzv6NxOmn6LXTngG?p=preview to get more of an understanding of what I'm trying to describe. (Note **touchscreen required**, or use Touch emulation in Chrome DevTools)

I've also created an issue [#9864](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9864) in the Angular repo, but haven't had any response. I understand they are busy getting ready for final, but in my opinion this should be solved before final as a lot of users will use Angular on touch devices.

I'd appreciate any tips/workarounds/hacks. Feel free to update the plunker with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

TouchEvents do actually continue to fire after DOM removal **BUT** they are only targeted at the node/element that the original `touchstart` occurred on and don't bubble (unlike MouseEvents, which is confusing!).

So, we cant perform a simple `@HostListener('touchmove', ['$event'])` and expect it to work with DOM removal (as the event listener is attached to the outer component element). We have to **dynamically** add event listeners to the **target element** of the **touchstart** event as they occur. Then perform cleanup on `touchend` or `touchcancel` (or `ngOnDestroy()`).

Soln:

```
@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  dragStart(event) {
    if (event.touches) {    // avoid touch event loss issue
      this.removePreviousTouchListeners();    // avoid mem leaks      
      this.touchmoveListenFunc = this.renderer.listen(event.target, 'touchmove', (e) => { this.onDragMove(e); });
      this.touchendListenFunc = this.renderer.listen(event.target, 'touchend', (e) => { this.removePreviousTouchListeners(); this.onDragEnd(e); });
      this.touchcancelListenFunc = this.renderer.listen(event.target, 'touchcancel', (e) => { this.removePreviousTouchListeners(); this.onDragEnd(e); });
    }
   ...
}

removePreviousTouchListeners() {
    if (this.touchmoveListenFunc !== null)
      this.touchmoveListenFunc();             // remove previous listener
    if (this.touchendListenFunc !== null)
      this.touchendListenFunc();              // remove previous listener
    if (this.touchcancelListenFunc !== null)
      this.touchcancelListenFunc();           // remove previous listener

    this.touchmoveListenFunc = null;
    this.touchendListenFunc = null;
    this.touchcancelListenFunc = null;
  }

 @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  // @HostListener('touchmove', ['$event'])    // don't declare this, as it is added dynamically
  onDragMove(event) {
    ...   // do stuff with event
  }

@HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  // @HostListener('touchend', ['$event'])     // don't use these as they are added dynamically
  // @HostListener('touchcancel', ['$event']) // don't use these as they are added dynamically
  onDragEnd(event) {
    ...  // do stuff
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.removePreviousTouchListeners();
```

Don't forget to inject `Renderer` in the constructor (import from `@angular/core`

Source https://plus.google.com/+RickByers/posts/GHwpqnAFATf